# Doctrine2 does not generate getter/setter

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to reverse engineer a db schema using Doctrine.

If i do

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities NS/MyBundle/Entity/MyClassName
```

it successfully creates a class with private properties taken from DB, but there are not getter/setter method, so that i cannot use it. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Try running `php app/console doctrine:generate:entities NS` after your first `app/console` command. If that also does not generate your entities, there might be something wrong. Let me know if it worked, then I'll write it as an answer.

Comment: No, it didn't worked. It generates the class but there are no get/set methods.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow [How to generate entities from existing database?](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html) As I don't think what you are doing is really going to work.